# PHP search query results used as form variable

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

This project I am working on I have a search form that lists the results into a table, I added two submit forms into the loop that if clicked should transfer the result to another table. But when I click on the submit button it just refreshes the page. I've changed the name and value of the form as well as tried quotes in the value in and out of the PHP and a few other changes with the same result. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

```
?>
            <table>
            <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Brewery</th>
                 <th>City</th>
                 <th>State</th>
                 <th>Style</th>
                 <th>ABV</th>
                 <th>IBU</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $result['Name']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['Brewery']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['City']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['State']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['Style']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['ABV'];?> </td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['IBU']; ?></td>
                 <td>

                 <form method="post" name="ontap" action="form.php">
                     <input type="hidden" name="name3" value=<?php echo $result['Name'] ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="brewery3" value=<?php echo $result['Brewery']; ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="city3" value=<?php echo $result['City']; ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="state3" value=<?php echo $result['State']; ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="style3" value=<?php echo $result['Style']; ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="abv3" value=<?php echo $result['ABV']; ?>>
                     <input type="hidden" name="ibu3" value=<?php echo $result['IBU']; ?>>
                     <input type="submit" name="ontap" value="On Tap">
                     </form> </td>
                         <?php
                         if(isset($_POST['ontap'])){

                             $name3 = $_POST['name3'];
                             $brewery3 = $_POST['brewery3'];
                             $city3 = $_POST['city3'];
                             $state3 = $_POST['state3'];
                             $style3 = $_POST['style3'];
                             $abv3 = $_POST['abv3'];
                             $ibu3 =$_POST['ibu3'];

                             mysqli_connect($conn,"INSERT INTO `Test` (`Name`, `Brewery`, `City`, `State`, `Style`, `ABV`, `IBU`) VALUES ('".$name3."', '".$brewery3."', '".$city3."', '".$state3."', '".$style3."', '".$abv3."', '".$ibu3."')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));   

                             echo("Beer Added");                                 

                             }
                             ?>                                        



                 <td>
                     <form  method="post" action="form.php"  id="bottle">
                     <input type="submit" name="bottle" value="bottle"> </form></td>
             </tr>    
             </table>

             <?php
```

I've still been having the same issue with the page refreshing. Made a few changes that were suggested and none seemed to work. But so far the mysqli_connect was changed to mysqli_query. I've put each input name into a bracket ontap['name3']; etc. Left the action value blank. I noticed that each variable pulled into the form only uses the first word as well. Ill try to upload a picture of the form being used
[searchformwithtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRoiF.png)

Comment: If your form add a new row, you need to execute the INSERT query before SELECT one.

Comment: Your forms is not getting submitted. Make the action in form blank i.e action=" "  and try.

Comment: I left the action blank and I made the change to mysqli_query but it is still just refreshing the page. Is there a way to see if the form is submitting the variable values?

Answer (score 0):

**mysqli_connect()** is for opening a new connection to the MySQL server.
You can use it like:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(server,username,password,database);
```

And if you want to insert data into your table, you need to use **mysqli_query()** for that purpose. You can use it like:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `Test` (`Name`, `Brewery`, `City`, `State`, `Style`, `ABV`, `IBU`) VALUES ('$name3', '$brewery3', '$city3', '$state3', '$style3', '$abv3', '$ibu3')";

$result = $mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result) {
   echo 'Beer Added';
}
```

Rest everything is okay. Make this change and it should work.

Comment: Please do use isset(), wherever you are fetching value from a variable, failure to use isset() will result in error if the variable does not contain any value under.

Comment: @Beau you can check that if the form is submitting the value or not by using isset() in the following way: if(isset($__POST['name3']) { echo 'Something'; }

Comment: You can check similarly for all variables

Comment: Sorry unable to comment in above thread as I don't have 50 reputations ;)